SQL Server Job Schedule needed to dynamically update based on a table
I have Job schedule as such: Runs daily Mon-Friday between 9:29 and 16:31 in 1 minute intervals.
I need to dynamically modify it: Meaning on some days it will need to run 9:29 to 12 noon and on other days it needs to get skipped completely.
I will have this information in another table.
Schedule table
DDate | Frequency
2024/11/27 | Full Day
2024/11/28 | Skip Day
2024/11/29 | Half Day

How do I write the SQL to automatically take care of this?

Its not the job you would modify it is the steps. If you have 1 step that runs a stored procedure then edit the stored procedure. Have it  join on your Schedule table and use a case within your where clause to check the time of day vs ddate and frequency

You are far better off defining the start/end times in your data, rather than ambiguous values like "half day".

Not to mention that your sample data has both "Skip Day" and "Half Day" on the same date.

On 2024/11/28  do we skip it, half, it or quarter it?

You might want one table that defines Schedule ID, Schedule Name, and Start/End times. A second table can relate dates to Schedule ID. You can leave your SQL Server Agent job as is, but have your job check those tables to see if the current date/time matches conditions that require it to "exit without doing any work".

You can create controlling-job that run once a day, probably immediately after midnight, that modify the start and end time of your job based on your start/end trigger criteria which can be saved in a table.
The controlling-job should execute the following T-SQL script
declare @active_starttime char(6);
declare @active_endtime char(6);

select @active_starttime = active_starttime, @active_endtime = active_endtime 
from sched_table
where ...
   ; 
EXEC msdb.[dbo].[sp_update_schedule] @name = N'Your_job_name', 
        @active_start_time = @active_starttime,
        @active_end_time = @active_endtime;


Awesome, I will definitely try that and I think this makes the most sense.
